# Copy or move files to another directory based on partial names in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

I want to copy some files from directory `A` to directory `B` on basis of partial filenames which are in a text file.

I tried the command below, but it's not working

```
for fn in $(cat filename.txt); do find . -type -f -name '$fn*' \
    -exec rsync -aR '{}' /tmp/test2 \;
```

File names are in format `abcd-1234-opi.txt`, `rety-4567-yuui.txt`. I have to grep numbers from file names and then copy those files to another folder, I have numbers in a text file.

Can anybody guide me?

Comment: I struggle to see a pattern. Can you give a better example? Be precise about the file name structure.

Comment: file names are in format abcd-1234-opi.txt, rety-4567-yuui.txt , i have to grep numbers from file names and then copy those files to another folder, i have numbers in a text file

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly, the pattern to search for is the first 3 digits of the numbers after the first `-`, like this:

> ```
> abd-12312-xyz
>     ^^^
>
> 88-45644-oio
>    ^^^
>
> qwe-78908-678
>     ^^^
> ```

Here's one way to write that:

```
while read line; do
    pattern=${line#*-}
    pattern=${pattern:0:3}
    find . -type f -name "*$pattern*" -exec rsync -aR {} /tmp/test2 \;
done < patterns.txt
```

If your inputs are like "veeram_20171004-104805_APOLLO_9004060859-all.txt",
and you want to extract the "9004060859",
then you can try to find a different logic to extract that.
For example,
"cut off every after the last '-', and everything before the last '_'".
You can write like this:

```
pattern=${line%-*}
pattern=${pattern##*_}
```

Comment: Janos, i have 9 digits in file name, example **veeram_20171004-104805_APOLLO_9004060859-all.txt**  i have to copy file name that contains 9004060859 to another folder , numbers i have in text file

Comment: @VijayMuddu that's a completely different pattern from what is in your question. So what is the pattern? The last sequence of numbers?

Comment: yes the last sequence of numbers in above example file name that contains 9004060859 , i have numbers in a text file

Comment: @ Janos i tried but i got this error,  >while read line; do
> pattern=${line%-*}
> pattern=${pattern##*_}
> find . -type -f -name "*$pattern*" -exec rsync -aR {} /tmp/test2 \;
> done < patterns.txt
find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter

Comment: @VijayMuddu I see now you had another mistake in the `find` command's arguments: it should be `-type f` instead of `-type -f`. So drop the `-` from in front of `f`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct:

```
for file in $(<./example); do cp "${file}" /tmp/test2/; done

for file in $(<./example); do find . -type f -name ${file} -exec rsync -aR {} /tmp/test2/ \; ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `find` repeatedly should probably be avoided.  Instead, factor the expressions into the `find` command line programmatically.

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf "find . -type -f \\("; sep="" }
   { printf "%s -name \047*%s*\047", sep, $0; sep=" -o" }
   END { printf " \\) -exec rsync -aR '{}' /tmp/test2 \\;\n" }' filename.txt |
sh
```

Leave off the pipe to `sh` to test.